# How to retrieve all document ids from a collection?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all of the document ids in a collection `groups`. The document id is the group name which is unique. Also each document in `groups` **does not have fields**, only pointers to other collections. I wrote the following code:

```
fireDB.collection("groups").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshots = task.getResult();
            if (querySnapshots != null) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot currentDocumentSnapshot : querySnapshots) {
                    groups.add(currentDocumentSnapshot.getId());
                }
                Collections.sort(groups);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(SignUpActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,groups);
                groupNameText.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "No groups in the database");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "addOnCompleteListener:failed");
        }
    }
});
```

But `groups` is always empty because firebase does not give me documents without fields (figured it out after some debugging). How should I do it?

Comment: I wonder how did you create documents without fields in `groups` and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sounds like you have some subcollections under document paths, without having a document at that path. This is a valid situation, but I don't think it is possible to get those locations in the client-side SDKs, as there is no document there.

See https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/b0poug/empty_virtual_docs_this_document_does_not_exist/

The Firebase console shows these locations in italics, since it needs to show the subcollections under each location. It likely uses the `show_missing` flag in the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#google.firestore.v1.ListDocumentsRequest) or Admin SDK for that.